# NameError: name 'dot' is not defined while computing similarities using word2vec

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, word2vec, tf.keras

I used this function to compute similarities using word2vec
I used keras and tensorflow

```
def cosine_distance (model, word,target_list , num) :
    cosine_dict ={}
    word_list = []
    a = model[word]
    for item in target_list :
        if item != word :
            b = model [item]
            cos_sim = dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))
            cosine_dict[item] = cos_sim
    dist_sort=sorted(cosine_dict.items(), key=lambda dist: dist[1],reverse = True) ## in Descedning order 
    for item in dist_sort:
        word_list.append((item[0], item[1]))
    return word_list[0:num]

# only get the unique Maker_Model
Maker_Model = list(df.Maker_Model.unique()) 

# Show the most similar Mercedes-Benz SLK-Class by cosine distance 
cosine_distance (model,'Mercedes-Benz SLK-Class',Maker_Model,5)
```

And received this error :

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-584408bf6259> in <module>
     17 
     18 # Show the most similar Mercedes-Benz SLK-Class by cosine distance
---> 19 cosine_distance (model,'Mercedes-Benz SLK-Class',Maker_Model,5)

<ipython-input-29-584408bf6259> in cosine_distance(model, word, target_list, num)
      6         if item != word :
      7             b = model [item]
----> 8             cos_sim = dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))
      9             cosine_dict[item] = cos_sim
     10     dist_sort=sorted(cosine_dict.items(), key=lambda dist: dist[1],reverse = True) ## in Descedning order

NameError: name 'dot' is not defined
```

I tried updating tensorflow and keras as suggested in one of the answers on the site but couldn't fix it. How should I fix this?
*Please help me out here.*

Comment: a and b are 2 one dimensional numpy arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `dot` is not recognized as a method.

In order to fix the issue, you need to do one of the following:

1. Specify which module's `dot` method you are trying to use. Like this:

```py
import numpy as np
...
np.dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))
```

2. Define a custom `dot` method.

```py
def dot(x, y):
   ...
```

3. Import a `dot` method to use.

This is similar to the first option except that you don't need to prepend your `dot` method call with the module name because you're importing the *method*, not the module.

```py
from numpy import dot
```

Here, I'm using numpy as an example library, but it could be any library containing a `dot` method:

- [numpy.dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)
- [pandas.DataFrame.dot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html)
- etc